# Почему флекс себя так ведет?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

```css
$lato : 'Lato'
$pt : 'PT'

$text_color : rgb( 10, 13, 16 )
$text_white_color : #f1f0f0
$red_color : #c61b2b
$black_color : #0a0d10

/**/
$xs: 0px
$sm: 575px
$md: 767px
$lg: 991px
$xl: 1199px

*
 margin: 0
 padding: 0

.main__wrapper
 width: 100%

//header

header
 margin: 0 2.64%
 display: flex
 justify-content: space-between
 align-items: center
 padding: 18px
 .header__right-info
  display: flex
  align-content: space-between
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: flex-end
  .right-info__light-menu
   display: block
   img
    display: inline-block
    margin-left: 1%
   ul
    display: inline-block
    li
     display: inline-block
     margin-left: 1.05%
     a
      text-decoration: none
      color: #5c5f62
  .right-info__huge-menu
   display: flex
   nav
    ul
     li
      display: inline-block
      margin-left: 2.95%
      a
       text-decoration: none
       color: $black_color 
       font-size: 14px
       font-family: $lato
       font-weight: 700
       text-transform: uppercase
```

```html
<main class="main__wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="header__logo">
            <img src="img/additional/main_logo.png" alt="logotype">
        </div>
        <div class="header__right-info">
            <div class="right-info__light-menu">
                <img src="img/additional/search_ico.png" alt="search_icon">
                <img src="img/additional/profile_ico.png" alt="profile_icon">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Eng</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">О проекте</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">На сайт музея</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right-info__huge-menu">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Персоналии</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Экспедиции</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Экспонаты</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Выставки</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Комплекты</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Тематические альбомы</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Коллекции</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</main>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmeMjz - Песочница

Почему два меню переходят на новую строку, хотя место есть, если отступы убрать, то такого нет.

Скриншот проблемы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще вопрос, как сделать что бы два меню оттолкнулись друг от друга на одинаковое расстояние не используя `margin`? Есть такое свойство, как 
`align-content: space-between`, но оно не помогает (На скриншоте этот отступ сделан `margina'ми`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос поставлен плохо, но всё же.

1)

```
.header__right-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 160px;
}
```

за чёт column и space-between - мы управляем расстоянием между light-menu huge-menu c помощью высоты.

2) right-info__light-menu - если мы говорим о нём , то места ему не хватает. Как вариант добавить ему display:flex. Или просто min-width: 430px;

Comment: А что насчет того, что пункты меню переходят на новую строку? Хотя места еще много

Comment: Дополнил ответ.